# Don't output same items from array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react js. I try to map an array with objects and to output the name of each object from array:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name:"Bill",
    age:88
  },
   {
    name:"Bill",
    age:18
  },
   {
    name:"Jack",
    age:55
  },
]
  {arr.map(i => (
        <li key={i.id}>
          {i.name}
        </li>
   ))}
```

I want to avoid the same name when i do `{i.name}`. For this i made this:

```js
{new Set(i.name)}
```

.. but it does not help. How to avoid displaying the same name in map function?

Comment: You have to filter out values. It can be done in various ways. One way would be to have an object and push only those keys which are not present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a Set of names before mapping and rendering. You can do it like below

```
  {[...new Set(arr.map(i => i.name))].map(i => (
        <li key={i.id}>
          {i.name}
        </li>
   ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) to overcome this issue. Following code snippet will easily do what you need.

```
_.uniqBy(arr,"name").map(i => (
    <li key={i.id}>
      {i.name}
    </li>
```

))}

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the duplicates from the `arr` based on the `name` property in each object and then use array `map()` method on it like:

```
{[...new Map(arr.map(i=> [i.name, i])).values()].map(i => (
   <li key={i.id}>
      {i.name}
   </li>
))}
```

**Demo:**

```js
const arr = [{name:"Bill",age:88},{name:"Bill",age:18},{name:"Jack",age:55}];

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<div>
      {[...new Map(arr.map(i=> [i.name, i])).values()].map(i => (
        <li key={i.id}>
          {i.name}
        </li>
      ))}
    </div>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```